# What is the probability that Asni is selected to be the monitor, Barun the assistant monitor and Culian the treasurer?

Tags: probability

One of the questions in my workbook read "

> Asni, Barun and Culian are from a class of 40 students.
> Three students are to be selected to be the monitor, assistant monitor and treasurer. What is the probability that Asni is selected to be the monitor, Barun the assistant monitor and Culian the treasurer?.

My answer is $1/9880$ while the book's answer is $1/59280$. Please explain to me why I did not get the same answer as the book and how to get the correct answer.

Here's my working:
$$3! \cdot \frac{1}{40}  \cdot \frac{1}{39} \cdot \frac{1}{38} = \frac{1}{9880}$$

The reason of why I multiply by $3!$ is because the order of the selections of the monitor, assistant monitor and treasurer do not matter. For example:

1)the monitor can be selected first, followed by the assistant monitor, followed by the treasurer

2)the monitor can be selected first, followed by the treasurer, followed by the assistant monitor.

3)the treasurer can be selected first, followed by the monitor, followed by the assistant monitor.

4)the treasurer can be selected first, followed by the assistant monitor, followed by the monitor.

5)the assistant monitor can be selected first, followed by the monitor, followed by the treasurer.

6)the assistant monitor can be selected first, followed by the treasurer, followed by the monitor.

Comment: The $3!$ is not needed as the positions are assigned beforehand, you do not require to permute the students

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Your result is the probability that those three students are chosen for the three positions, but ignoring who is in which position.

Comment: To elaborate, think of it this way, we select 3 students in 40C3 ways, and assign them a position in $3!$ Ways, only one of these selections gives the three mentioned students, furthermore there is only one way to assign the positions, giving 1/$\binom{40}{3}3!$ .Or you could just select each kid one by one 1/(40*39*38)

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of ways to think about this.

One way to think about it is that you don't multiply by $3!$ because "order" comes from the different roles. You need Asni as monitor, Barun as assistant monitor and Culian as treasurer. You wouldn't accept Barun as monitor, Asni as assistant monitor and Culian as treasurer. There are $3!$ ways to assign those students to those roles, and if any of those was acceptable, then you would have $3!$ as your numerator. Only one of those is acceptable, so your numerator is 1.

Another way to think about it is to put the problem explicitly into mathematical language. Pretend for now that there are only 26 students in the class, labeled $A,B,C,\ldots,Z$. We can write the monitor, assistant monitor, and treasurer as a string of 3 different letters, e.g. $ABJ$ if Asni is monitor, Barun is assistant monitor and Jacob is treasurer. There are $26\times25\times24$ possible strings, and only one of these strings is $ABC$, i.e. only one of these strings corresponds to Asni as monitor, Barun as assistant monitor and Culian as treasurer, so the probability of $ABC$ is $\frac{1}{26 \times 25 \times 24}$. Again, you would multiply by $3!$ if all the strings $ABC,ACB,BAC,BCA,CAB,CBA$ were acceptable, but they aren't, so you don't. It doesn't matter that you could have chosen a different way of writing the strings, and if you did then a different string would be acceptable (i.e. you could have made the first letter represent the assistant monitor and the second letter represent the monitor). You choose one way of converting sets of roles into strings, and you only consider strings that are acceptable for that one way of converting.

Answer (score 1):

Long-winded comment:  
**Not an answer**.

Assuming that this problem is from a book or class, you have a deeper problem.  Normally, when you encounter a problem in the middle of a book or class course, there is training (e.g. worked examples, theorems, previously solved problems) that are supposed to have increased your comprehension of the concepts.

Something has gone off the rails re your learning of the entire topic (e.g. Probability Theory and/or Combinatorics).  Apparently, you have attempted to learn the material by rote memorization, rather than understanding.  In the study of Mathematics, this is a recipe of disaster.

This is why you are having trouble, with this problem, and why the difficulties that you will have with this subject will worsen.  To avoid further trouble, and dig yourself out of the intellectual hole (assuming that you prefer not to abandon the study of the course), you have to treat the study of Math as a foreign language.  This analogizes to either becoming fluent enough in Swahili that you could pass for a native, or becoming so skilled at the piano that you could play in a symphony.

Just as a pianist gets the *feel* of the piano, and someone fluent in Swahili *thinks* in terms of Swahili (rather than translating into English, thinking of a response in English, and then translating it back into Swahili), the Math student succeeds by learning to *think* in terms of Math.

For this course, the way to do that is to go back to Page 1 of the book or the beginning of the class notes, slowly re-examine the material, and work on many Math problems related to the material.  For me, with respect to all Math at the undergraduate level or below, about $80\%$ of the learning takes place in the Math problems that you grapple with, not the material that you are introduced to.

You have to work so many exercises that the application of the material becomes 2nd nature to you, and you develop a deep understanding of the relationship between the theorems/worked examples and the Math problems that you are asked to solve.

Your posting shows good effort, and the back and forth comments following your posting also show good effort.  The posting and comments also show that you are lost.

If the book/class that you are using/involved in doesn't feature that many Math problems, find a supplemental source that does.  It is the Math problems that teach you to think in terms of Math as a foreign language.

Comment: I disagree strongly with this mindset. It's much better to ask questions and understand the theory than it is to practice over and over. Grappling with problems before you understand the theory just means training yourself to make mistakes. Grapple with problems as well, but not until you understand the notes you've received, or at least grapple with problems as a way to understand your notes.

Comment: @1Rock I like that the OP (i.e. original poster) is asking questions.  However, I think that the OP needs to start the course over.

Comment: Again, I disagree. For most courses, it's possible to learn the content in at most a week or two, if you dedicate enough time to it and you have good resources, and you use them appropriately. Also, this is one question the student doesn't understand. Their approach probably works for 70% of the problems. And sticking with the course to the end is better than dropping out and trying again next term.

Comment: @1Rock I think that we should agree to disagree.